# How to solve "Cannot Get /" error on AWS deployment?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, devops

My app is working fine when i deploy it on `Heroku`. When i push it to AWS elastic beanstalk it gives me a page that says `Cannot Get /`.

The log looks like this:

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log
-------------------------------------

> react-express-starter@0.1.0 dev /var/app/current
> run-p server start

sh: run-p: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! react-express-starter@0.1.0 dev: `run-p server start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react-express-starter@0.1.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Express server is running on localhost:8081
```

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/error.log
-------------------------------------
2020/04/07 03:46:43 [error] 5546#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 206.188.72.122, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/", host: "reacttwilio-env.eba-ugm2xpnb.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2020/04/07 03:46:44 [error] 5546#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 206.188.72.122, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/favicon.ico", host: "reacttwilio-env.eba-ugm2xpnb.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://reacttwilio-env.eba-ugm2xpnb.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
2020/04/07 04:04:00 [error] 5546#0: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 206.188.72.122, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/", host: "reacttwilio-env.eba-ugm2xpnb.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2020/04/07 04:04:00 [error] 5546#0: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 206.188.72.122, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/favicon.ico", host: "reacttwilio-env.eba-ugm2xpnb.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://reacttwilio-env.eba-ugm2xpnb.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
```

These get printed for like 10 times each.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-express-starter",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
   ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "server": "node-env-run server --exec nodemon | pino-colada",
    "server:prod": "node server",
    "dev": "server start"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.x"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
   ...
  }
}
```

server -> index.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "build")));

const sendTokenResponse = (token, res) => {
  res.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
  res.send(
    JSON.stringify({
      token: token.toJwt()
    })
  );
};

app.get("/api/greeting", (req, res) => {
  const name = req.query.name || "World";
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  res.send(JSON.stringify({ greeting: `Hello ${name}!` }));
});

app.get("/video/token", (req, res) => {
  const identity = req.query.identity;
  const room = req.query.room;
  const token = videoToken(identity, room, config);
  sendTokenResponse(token, res);
});
app.post("/video/token", (req, res) => {
  const identity = req.body.identity;
  const room = req.body.room;
  const token = videoToken(identity, room, config);
  sendTokenResponse(token, res);
});

app.listen(config.port, () =>
  console.log(`Express server is running on localhost:${config.port}`)
);
```

I tried changing my scripts to `npm run dev` cause that's how i start it locally but that gives me `502 bad gateway` error.

Comment: Your real error is this `run-p: command not found`. I don't know what run-p is, but it looks like you need to install it.

Comment: @Jordanm what can i replace it with?

Comment: What do you mean replace? Install the tool

Comment: it is giving me a page that says `Cannot Get /`

Comment: when i request something from /video/token, it gives me the token. which is expected. But only the homepage is not showing up.

Comment: @jordanm can i get some help with that?

Comment: I made a suggestion and you seemed to ignore it.

Comment: i am sorry that it sounded like that. i really didn't mean to. i tried it but didn't work. `run -p` is an npm shortcut to run two commands parallel it works in my localhost but doesn't when i push to AWS.

Comment: i have the dependency in my `package.json` as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211161/discussion-between-phyxable-and-jordanm).

Comment: If it's in your package.json, you probably just need to specify an absolute path to it. Alternatively, you can install it on the instance using `npm install -g npm-run-all` either through the buildfile or through the predeploy platform hook.

Answer (score 1):

What I see, is that you are not defining a response for route "/". 
You can do it like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// respond with "hello world" when a GET request is made to the homepage
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('hello world');
});
```

The issue is because when you push it on elastic beanstalk, it goes by default to root site. Maybe you can redirect to other route to avoid that behaviour.

Comment: yea that is working, what i want to send as the response is a component that is written in `React`. When i require that component and try to send it back it tells me that `Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

Comment: Can i see your complete code? Maybe through github?

Comment: lemme know once you get it. i will remove my repo off here.

Comment: I got the link. I didn't found where you are requering the component and sending. What file should I see?

Comment: please take a look at the server folder then index.js

Comment: oh, this is server side redering what you want, doesn't it? Saw something similar in this Github issue: https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1625#issuecomment-560115741
Give it a try